# How to quickly gather a list of points by following adjacent criterium

Tags: python, contour, image-recognition, surface

I have a list of points `L=[[x1,y1],[x2,y2],...]` and I would like to build a list `S=[L1,L2,...]` of "surface" generated by gathering the neighbor points of `L`. The type of "surface" is the same as the type of L, that is to say, a list of points (but that constitute a surface based on neighbor linking). However, what I have tried to do is not fast enough.

I used a recursive function `F(L, P)` that requires a list of points `L`, and the start point `P=[x,y]` (which has to be removed from the list `L` when the function is called). Then, it looks for all the neighbor points of `P` and callback the function on each one of them if they exist (after removing them from `L`). The base case is reached when the point tested has no longer neighbor points.

Thus, when all the base case is reached, `F(L, P)` returns a list of points `L1` that constitute the `surface` associated to `P`. I then repeat the process for the remaining points of `L` and so on to build `L2,L3,...`.

```py
def F(L,P):   
    nhList=[]
    leftP=[P[0]+1,P[1]]
    rightP=[P[0]-1,P[1]]
    upP=[P[0],P[1]-1]
    dwP=[P[0],P[1]+1] 

    if(upP in L):
        L.remove(upP)
        nhList.append(upP)
    if(dwP in L):
        L.remove(dwP)
        nhList.append(dwP)
    if(leftP in L):
        L.remove(leftP)
        nhList.append(leftP)
    if(rightP in L):
        L.remove(rightP)
        nhList.append(rightP)

    if(nhList!=[]):
        rtList=[P]
        for ad in nhList:
            e=F(L,ad)
            rtList+=e
        return rtList
    else:
        return [P]

L=[[0,0],[1,0],[5,3],[1,1],[5,4],[2,2]] # e.g.
S=[]
while(L!=[]):
    P=L.pop()
    S.append(F(L,P))
print(S)
# Returns [[2, 2]], [[5, 4], [5, 3]], [[1, 1], [1, 0], [0, 0]] as expected
```

I expect to retrieve the list `S` as explained in the intro, and it works well. However, when I use this process on a bigger list of points (that contains 1M points for instance) it slows down the processing and sometimes, I even reach the recursion limit.

Therefore, I'm looking to generate the list `S` faster.

Comment: Just to be sure I understand correctly `L=[[x1,y1],[x2,y2],...]` and the first time you want `P` to be `[x1, y1]` (the second time it will be the first non-neighbor of `[x1, y1]` from `L`, etc.)? When you say neighbor, reading your code I understand that means "at distance at most one in a grid" (x ± 1 or y ± 1)?

Comment: Ah also, how fast do you expect this to be?

Comment: Yes, the value of P2 will be the last one of L if the list is not empty (as I use L.pop() to retrieve P2). This new point can't be a neighbor of P as the function F(L,P) removed every points of L that where neighbor to P and every points neighbor to those that where neighbor to P and so on ...

Comment: As for the execution time, I would like something < 15 ms for 100 000 points in L

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can enhance the performance by following ideas:

1. in big data to avoid `recursion limit`, you can use `iteration` instead of `recursion`
2. to enhance the perfomance of `query` and `modify` in `L`, you can preprocess `L` into a `set`
3. for algorithm, `BFS` is suitable here.

here is my solution:

```
from collections import deque

L = [[0, 0], [1, 0], [5, 3], [1, 1], [5, 4], [2, 2]]  # e.g.
# convert to set for query and modify performance, change list to immutable tuple.
L = set(map(tuple, L))

S = []
while L:
    # start from a random point
    start = L.pop()
    queue, visited, cur_s = deque([start]), set([start]), [start]

    while queue:
        node = queue.popleft()
        visited.add(node)
        i, j = node
        # find the 4-adjacent neighbors
        for neighbor in (i + 1, j), (i - 1, j), (i, j + 1), (i, j - 1):
            if neighbor in L and neighbor not in visited:
                queue.append(neighbor)
                cur_s.append(neighbor)
                L.remove(neighbor)
    S.append(cur_s)

print(S)
```

output:

```
[[(5, 4), (5, 3)], [(0, 0), (1, 0), (1, 1)], [(2, 2)]]
```

Hope that helps you, and comment if you have further questions. : )

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer. I tested your code with different length of lists and I noticed it drastically reduces the time needed to process  L when its length increase. Indeed your code is 75% faster than mine when the length of L is arround 10 000. However, it still lasts 700ms  but I would hope for something like 70ms :(. Am I looking for something too ambitious ? Thanks for your answer :)

Comment: I have an idea to speed up is `divide & conquer`,  you can split `L` by space, something like that [`Quadtree`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree), and use map-reduce to compute in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

I found an interesting function from opencv when I look for Quadtrees. It takes ~80ms to process a 10.000 points list `L`.

`connectedComponents(InputArray image, OutputArray labels, int connectivity=8, int ltype=CV_32S)`